# javascript: how to pass window.open("URL") single numeric response to variable on parent html page

Tags: javascript

I have html page say **page1** window.open("https:www.abc.com/id=5468"). This will open page which is having only numeric response (say 12345 as a response,rest whole page got nothing). How i will pass this "12345" in the textbox on **page1**?

Thanks,
Vikas.

Comment: Why do you need a window for that? window.opener or window.postMessage() could do it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: Look into ```AJAX```

Comment: It‘s not 100% clear what you‘re trying to reach exactly. Does the opened window have an Ajax call in background?

Comment: I have this kind of function on HTML page 1, on button click this will hit the below URL and its response will be some Numeric ID say :5554655 which will be generated in new window or browser tab.

function member_insert() {

if (document.getElementById("aa").value == "")
{
window.open("https://example.com/csp/RemoteServlet?&zip=94086&hph=9876543210"); 
  }

I need this value 5554655 to be displayed in textbox at page 1.

Comment: No Ajax..just a plain HTML page.

Comment: There is no point in cross sending information if you do not have to. What is the point of the second page? Anyway if you do not want to use Ajax there is no possible way to do it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage